# How to display underline in javascript string?

Tags: javascript, string, literals

I have the following javascript code:

```
var result = ("Please enter your name","Andrew");
```

and i wanted to underline the word `"name"` in the above message.

This is trivial but i have no clue after searching for escape code representation for underline. Or is the above possible in javascript ?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. It's equivalent to `var result = "Andrew";`, the first string is just discarded. Besides, any formatting like underlining depends on how you display the message, so you have to specify that also.

Comment: A demo of Guffa's comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fw9RX/

Comment: Maybe this is just a simplified example, but why do you want to underline "name"? Do you find a lot of users misread the question and enter their favourite colour?

Comment: he probably mean to put square bracket [ .. ] instead of the (...)

Answer (score 2):

If the example code given had a typo and should've read like this:

```
var result = window.prompt("Please enter your name","Andrew");
```

then the answer is that you can't format the text or change the labels on the buttons or anything. This applies to the built-in `alert()` and `confirm()` as well as to `prompt()`.

It's a bit more work, but you can implement your own equivalent dialog by building one from HTML using a transparent `<div>` to cover the rest of your page so that users can't interact with the rest of the page until the dialog closes. (Or use a translucent `<div>` to make it more obvious to the user that the rest of the page is "disabled".)

I would not bother coding this from scratch when there are lots of JS libraries that do it for you. The [jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) is pretty easy to use, to name just one option.

Comment: Thanks. Will explore jQuery dialog on this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is ending up on a web page you should just be able to use:

```
var result = ("Please enter your <u>name</u>","Andrew");
```

...but I'm not exactly sure what it is you're intending to do. Can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Note: The `u` tag is deprecated in HTML 4.

Comment: I made a typo error. It should be : var = prompt("Please enter name","Andrew"); I gotten the answer. The prompt cannot support display of underline.

Comment: Ah... I thought there was something missing there. Yea, if you want a custom prompt, you'll have to make your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = ("Please enter your <u>name</u>","Andrew");
```

Comment: Note: The `u` tag is deprecated in HTML 4.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. It is a typo, what i meant is the following